How to correctly align label for sections in titleformat?
I've been experimenting with custom sections for a bit, and I've been able to make the following work with titleformat when I don't use the label for my section (\section*{}):

When I include the label for my section (using \section{} instead), however, it's slightly misaligned, offset by a little to the right of the text width:

A "quickfix" I found myself by trying back and forth was adding \hspace{-0.2cm} to the label in titleformat, but I'm not certain if that's the correct way to fix it (or if it's even fixed - it could also be that the difference with it is so minimal that I don't notice it!). Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=1cm, hmargin=2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, xcolor, parskip, titlesec, tikz}

% For setting the header
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt} % Setting the size of the sep in the fbox

\renewcommand{\headruleskip}{-0.7em} % Placement of the headrule relative to the header text

\fancyhead[L]{\colorbox{red!60!black}{\color{white}\thepage} 
Random header text
}

\fancyhead[C]{Author}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{red!60!black} \rule{\headwidth}{2.5pt}} % Redefine the headrule (color, width, pattern etc.)

\fancyhead[R]{} % Just added an empty header to prevent auto appearance of section numbering in the header when using titleformat

% Custom section using the titlesec package
\titleformat{\section} % command level 
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % Size and text appearance (current is the standard)
{\hspace{-0.2cm}\Sectitle\thesection} % Label (standard is numbering, denoted by \thesection)
{-1em} % Distance of label from text (standard is 1em)
{\Sectitle} % Code after

\newcommand{\Sectitle}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, draw, left color=blue!50!white, right color=blue, inner sep = 8pt, text = white, minimum height=1.1cm] {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Experiment}
Practicing how to make beautiful headers and sections.

\end{document}

Note: I included my "quickfix" solution in the MWE so you can see how that looks and where in the code I was precisely referring to. Hopefully you can replace it with a more robust and correct solution:)

Your definition of \Sectitle has a spurious space at the start. Add a % to remove it, as suggested here: What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) (possible duplicate). For reference/completeness, see this code.

Oh wow, I always thought that adding the % was just to indicate the start of a curly brace containing a big chunk of code within - Never knew that it also removed the blank space added in the beginning. I guess it has to do with space and tab serving the same purpose, leaving a one character blank space, right?

Yes. The contents of the macro is inserted as-is where it's used. So, even if you were to leave a space between the opening brace { and the percent sign %, that would result in a space being inserted with every call to \Sectitle, causing the unwanted space you see. So, leave to gap between { and % (i.e., {% rather than { %) to avoid this unwanted (spurious) space from being inserted.
